# MVC 4 Razor User interface differences between Development Environment and IIS

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, user-interface, iis-7.5

Why differences the user interfaces, such as textbox, button, etc... between developing stage on local machine and IIS?When I'm developing with ASP.NET MVC 4 on my local machine, the user interface like below :
[image: from local machine : http ://localhost:00000/]

After I uploaded to server
[image: from Windows 2008 server R2, IIS 7.5]

How can solve this case? Please

Comment: It looks like the top picture is from Chrome and the bottom picture is from IE

Comment: @Jack Both are IE 10 bro

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that because one is rendering in the "localhost" domain that it is using IE's Compatibility View by default because it is considered to be an "intranet" zone. And the other is likely rendering from something that is considered to be in an "Internet" zone, so no Compatibility View by default.

Comment: Yes! you are right. This morning I saw this problem on my browser. After I changed from Compatibility View, It's working fine. Is there anything can define to show with normal view on _Layout.html?